# How to import a webpack bundle into service worker?

Tags: service-worker

I have been looking for a simple solution to importScript a full bundle created by webpack into a service worker. I have a few issues:

1. When I bundle a single file with webpack I can importScript this into my service worker. However, if I "require(import)" a file inside the file to be importScripted then the service worker complains that it does not know what export means. **How do I fix this?**
2. What format should my entry files be commonjs, umd...? Since importScript seems to just import the global functions of the file I don't even know if webpack is the right solution. **Is it?**   Other people seems to have used it.
3. Can I import any node_module component I want just like on normal client side bundling? **Are there limitations?**
4. **WHERE IS THE DOCUMENTATION???** Maybe I am misunderstanding something...

*thanks in advance*

Answer (score 0):

That's not how service workers work.

`importScripts` is designed to import *service worker* code, not your application code.

What you really want is auto-generated service worker, based on your bundle. You can use [this webpack plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sw-precache-webpack-plugin) that uses excellent [sw-precache](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache) under the hood.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using this but it is part of create-react-app so I don't want to change the configuration. At the moment I append a importScript to my SW generated by sw-precache so I don't have to play about with the internal configuration. It works but I want to be able to import a full bundle not just individual scripts. Some forum posts suggests this is possible in someway. So I thought best to ask if anyone new if this was possible. Basically, I want to add sync to my offline form using SW.